# How to change variables in a surface integral without parametrizing

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, intuition

This is a doubt that I carry since my PDE classes.

### Some background (skippable):

In the multivariable calculus course at my university we made all sorts of standard calculations involving surface and volume integrals in $R^3$, jacobians and the generalizations of the fundamental theorem of calculus. In order to make those calculations we had to parametrize domains and calculate differentials.

A couple of years later I took a PDE course. We worked with Evans' *Partial differential equations* book. This was my first experience with calculus in $\mathbb R^n$ and manipulations like 
$$\text{average}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)\,dy= \text{average}\int_{B(0,1)}f(x+rz)\,dz.$$
This was an ordinary change of variables. $y=x+rz,\,\,dy=r^n\,dz$ and the mystery was solved. Like in that case, I was able to justify most of these formal manipulations after disentangling definitions.

That aside, I found these quick formal calculations to be very powerful.

### However,

I realized that I wasn't able to justify this:
$$\text{average} \int_{\partial B(x,r)}f(y)dS(y)= \text{average}\int_{\partial B(0,1)}f(x+rz)\,dS(z).$$
I have some vague idea of what's happening: the same substitution as before, but this time the jacobian is $r^{n-1}$ because the transformation is actually happening between regions which "lack one dimension". Also, I see some kind of pattern: a piece of arc-length in the plane is $r\,d\theta$, a piece of sphere-area is $r^2 \sin\theta \, d\phi \,d\theta$, "and so on". Maybe some measure-theoretic argument can help me: I know, roughly speaking, that for any measure $\mu$, $$\int_\Omega f\circ \phi \,d\mu=\int_{\phi(\Omega)} f \, d(\mu\circ\phi^{-1}).$$ I'd say $\phi(z)=(z-x)/r$ and $\phi^{-1}(y)=ry+x$, but I actually don't know how $dS(y)$ looks like "as a measure" (It's not a product measure or a restriction of one, but it somehow relates to Lebesgue's in $\mathbb R^n$...). Why would I conclude that $dS(y)\circ \phi^{-1}=r^{n-1}dS(z)$? I have an intuition, but either I lack the mathematical concepts and definitions to express it or I'm just too confused. Is there some theory that I could learn in order to understand? Maybe something about the measure $dS$. Is it expressible in terms of the Lebesgue measure in some way? Or set-theoretically, maybe, without having to resort to $n-1$ parameters and complicated relations?

Maybe all of this would not have been a problem if I had ever mastered n-dimensional spherical coordinates. But even so, more generally, is there a way of changing variables when I'm integrating over a subregion of "dimension$<n$" *without necessarily parametrizing*?

Sorry for the vagueness, but I don't really know what to ask for exactly.

Note: I saw some of the answers to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481301/how-to-change-variables-in-the-function-phir-int-partial-bx-ruy-ds), but none of them were deep enough in the direction I intend.

Note II: If there are no general methods or theories, maybe restricting to linear transformations, to Lebesgue measure exclusively, or to subregions defined by simple expressions like $g(x)=C$ or $g(|x|)=C$ could get me somewhere.

---

Edit: I have not yet studied *differential geometry*, which has been mentioned in a comment. I added it to the tags.

Comment: There is a unifying framework for the question that's bothering you, [tag:differential-geometry]. In this case, we think of $dS$ as an "$(n-1)$-differential form" in $\Bbb R^n$, and integrate it along the "$(n-1)$-chain" which is your sphere. What you require is called a "pull-back" of $dS$ via the differentiable mapping $y\mapsto x+ry$. Hopefully, this might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JonathanY. Do you know any good books on the subject? Rigorous, with good prose, motivations, nice examples, maybe even illustrations (not a requirement, though). Also, is this some specific subtopic? The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry) mentions "Riemannian manifolds", "tensors", the *Theorema Egregium*, and "symplectic geometry". I wouldn't know exactly where to put my attention.

Comment: While I haven't formally studied differential geometry in its broadest setting, I have used parts of it and in this aspect the books [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Smooth-Manifolds-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1441999817/ref=pd_bxgy_b_text_z) and [Riemannian Manifolds](http://www.amazon.com/Riemannian-Manifolds-Introduction-Curvature-Mathematics/dp/0387983228/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1392279234&sr=8-1&keywords=john+lee+riemannian+manifolds) by John Lee were very...smooth. =)

Comment: @dafinguzman myself, I like Spivak's "calculus on manifolds" or "comprehensive introduction to differential geometry". You're looking for integration on chains/manifolds and the (proper instance of the) change of variable theorem.

Comment: seeing as this just got bumped to the home page, I thought I should just mention: the $dS$ you see can be interpreted in two ways, the first is as a differential form (of appropriate dimension assuming the submanifold is orientable... which the spheres are) or you can view this as a measure induced on the submanifold via the natural metric tensor. This is just a special case of a more general phenomenon: over any (pseudo-Riemannian) manifold, one can use the metric tensor to define a "Lebesgue"measure. Using the Radon-Nikodym derivative one can then formulate a change of variables theorem.

Comment: Thank you @peek-a-boo. Could you point to a source for checking out these perspectives?

Comment: I don't really have a specific source because my understanding is derived from several sources on multivariable calculus, differential geometry and real analysis (eg Loomis and Sternberg's advanced calculus, Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, Amann and Escher's Analysis Vol III chapter 12, Dieudonne's vol III, Folland's real analysis, Lee's smooth manifolds etc). You might want to start from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4059532/568204) and mayble followup with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4059532/568204). If you have a more specific qn I'd be happy to answer.

Comment: I guess the closest of these would be Loomis and Sternberg's chapter 10 where they talk about densities and Riemannian volume densities (they don't really talk about measures, but if you have some measure theory background you can easily fill in the detals). Also, Amann and Escher's book is very measure-theory oriented so you can learn a lot of the basic definitions there. Unfortunately none of these sources talk about the change-of variables theorem in the language of measure theory and Radon-Nikodym derivatives (presumably because measure-theory itself is a huge prerequisite).

Comment: I just realized I put the same link twice, my bad, the second link should be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4138970/568204). (it's about a slightly different and more difficult form of change of variables/Fubini, but some of the ideas are still there).

Comment: That's interesting @peek-a-boo. Those answers are far more advanced than what I had in mind when I asked the question, but thanks for sharing! I appreciate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I thought this explanation might be helpful to some.

---

By definition (in $\mathbb R^3$):

$$\int_{\partial B(\boldsymbol x,r)}f(\boldsymbol y)dS(\boldsymbol y)=
\int_U f(\boldsymbol y(s,t))\left\|\frac{\partial\boldsymbol y}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial\boldsymbol y}{\partial t}\right\|dsdt$$

Now, observe that $f(\boldsymbol y)=f(\boldsymbol x+r(\frac{\boldsymbol y-\boldsymbol x}{r}))$, and that if $\boldsymbol y(s,t)$ is a parametrization of $\partial B(\boldsymbol x,r)$ for $(s,t)\in U$, then $\frac{\boldsymbol y(s,t)-\boldsymbol x}{r}$ is a parametrization of $\partial B(\boldsymbol 0,1)$ for $(s,t)\in U$. Finally we observe that

$$\left\|\frac{\partial\boldsymbol y}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial\boldsymbol y}{\partial t}\right\|=
r^2\left\|\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left (\frac{\boldsymbol y-\boldsymbol x}{r} \right )\times\frac{\partial }{\partial t} \left (\frac{\boldsymbol y-\boldsymbol x}{r} \right )\right\|$$

So if we let $\boldsymbol z(s,t)=\frac{\boldsymbol y(s,t)-\boldsymbol x}{r}$, then we have

$$\int_U f(\boldsymbol y(s,t))\left\|\frac{\partial\boldsymbol y}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial\boldsymbol y}{\partial t}\right\|dsdt=
r^2\int_U f(\boldsymbol x +r\boldsymbol z(s,t))\left\|\frac{\partial\boldsymbol z}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial\boldsymbol z}{\partial t}\right\|dsdt\\=
r^2\int_{\partial B(\boldsymbol 0,1)}f(\boldsymbol x+r\boldsymbol z)dS(\boldsymbol z)$$

---

#### Edit by OP

As @user5753974 commented, you can generalize this if you use the fact that in $\mathbb R^n$ $$∫_{∂B(\boldsymbol x,r)}f(\boldsymbol y)dS(\boldsymbol y)=∫_{U}f(\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol z)) \left \|\det\left (\frac{∂\boldsymbol y}{∂z_1},…,\frac{∂\boldsymbol y}{∂z_{n−1}},\boldsymbol n\right) \right \| d^{n−1}\boldsymbol z,$$ where $\boldsymbol n$ is the normal vector to the surface, and that $\boldsymbol n$ does not change when the surface is scaled and translated.

Comment: This is great! I see that the cross product gets in the way of immediately generalising this reasoning to $\mathbb R^n$. I'm guessing this is more or less the role of the wedge products in Gil Bor's answer.

Comment: @dafinguzman I think you can generalize if you use the fact that in $\mathbb R^n$
$\int_{\partial B(\pmb x,r)}f(\pmb y)dS(\pmb y)=
\int_U f(\pmb y(\pmb z))\left|\det\left(\frac{\partial\pmb y}{\partial z_1},
\dots,\frac{\partial\pmb y}{\partial z_{n-1}},\pmb n\right)\right|d^{n-1}\pmb z$, where $\pmb n$ is the normal vector to the surface, and that $\pmb n$ does not change when the surface is scaled and translated.

Comment: @user5753974 Hi, is $\pmb z$ a $(n-1)$-tuple? And does $d^{n-1}\pmb z$ mean $dz_1 dz_2 ... dz_{n-1}$? Thanks!

Comment: Yes @SamWong, to both. Also, after adding user5753974 's comment I'm going to accept this answer, as it is the closest to what I had in mind when I originally asked the question. The definition of $dS$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with the determinant was probably the most important element I was missing in those days.

Answer (score 6):

No parametrization is needed, just some careful uncovering of definitions. Maybe the following can help:

Let $S^n(r)=\{x\in\mathbb R^{n+1}|\|x\|=r\}\subset\mathbb R^{n+1}$ (the sphere of radius $r>0$ centered at the origin).

There is a natural volume form $\mu_{r}$ on  $S^n(r)$,  i.e. a nowhere-vanishing $n$-form, induced by the volume form $\mu=dx_1\wedge\ldots \wedge dx_{n+1}$ on  $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and the  "outward" unit normal $N:S^n(r)\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$,  $N(x)=x/r$, and is defined as follows:

$$\mu_r(x)(v_1,\ldots,v_n):=\mu(x)(N(x), v_1, \ldots, v_n)$$ for all $v_1, \ldots, v_n\in T_x S^n(r).$

(More informally, we write $\mu_r=\mu/dr$. Note that $dr(N)=1$).

Next let  $\Phi:S^n(1)\to S^n(r)$ be defined by $\Phi(x)=rx$. Then $$\Phi^*\mu_r=r^n\mu_1. $$ This you can prove without any parametrization, just from the definitions above and generalities like  the chain rule, pull back, etc.

It then follows, by the change of variables formula, that for any continuous function $f:S^n(r)\to\mathbb R$, $$\int_{S^n(r)}f\mu_r=\int_{S^n(1)} \Phi^*(f\mu_r)=r^n\int_{S^n(1)} (f\circ\Phi) \mu_1.$$

Makes sense?

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate some definitions? I don't know what $n$-forms, $T_x$ or "pull back" are. As you present it, it seems that $\mu$ is a product measure, somehow. Also, I don't know what $dr(N)$ is supposed to mean. I can guess it means (by the notation) that "surface infinitesimal elements" get amplified by $1$ near the points which are on the sphere.

Comment: @dafinguzman: sorry, cannot elaborate, it's too long. I am using standard language taught in most  differential geometry courses. You need to take such a course or pick a textbook  (popular ones are  Spivak, Lee, Guillemin+Pollack. My personal favorite is Arnold's mathematical methods of classical mechanics, intuitive and rigorous at the same time; but it's not easy as a first textbook). Now I am sure it is possible to translate my answer to a more elementary language (although less rigorous). Perhaps another user of the site will try to do it (or even myself if I find the time and energy).

Comment: OK, after a long time I read through some chapters of Spivak's Calculus with Manifolds and now I get what you are trying to say. Trying to adapt to the definitions in Spivak, though, I find that $(\Phi ^ * \mu_r)(x)((v_1)_x,..., (v_n)_x) = r^n \mu (rx) (x, (v_1)_{rx}, ..., (v_n)_{rx})$. Then I'm tempted to say that equals $r^n \mu (x) (x, (v_1)_{x}, ..., (v_n)_{x})$ by "invariance of $\mu$ under translations", which is known for Lebesgue measure in $R^n$. Is that correct? Thanks for your answer: once the definition of "$dS$" is made explicit everything becomes clearer.

Answer (score 5):

I think the measure theoretic approach works fine, note that the surface measure is n-1 dimensional Hausdorff measure, in general for the s-dimensional Hausdorff measure we have $H^{s} (rA)=r^{s} H^{s}(A)$ and this measure is translation invariant. Now use the measure theoretic change of variable formula.

Comment: Does this mean that the measure $dS$ in the integral over $\partial B$ is the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure? I hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: Yes, the surface measure $dS$ which is used on the boundary of n-dimensional objects  is exactly the $n-1$ Hausdorff measure on the boundary.