# Proving Mean value property of harmonic functions using Divergence Theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am stuck at proving the mean value property of harmonic functions for an open domain $X \subset \mathbb{R^n}$: If $u \in C^2(X)$ is harmonic in $X$ and $\overline{B_r(y)} \subset X$, then:

$$u(y)=\frac{1}{\overline{B_1(0)}r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_r(y)} u \, ds$$

where $ds$ is the surface element.

Here's the proof I am going through:

$$0= \int_{B_r(y)} \Delta u\, dx=\int_{B_r(y)}\nabla \cdot \nabla u \,dx=\int_{\partial B_r(y)} \nabla u \cdot n \,ds=\int_{\partial B_r(y)} \nabla u\cdot \frac{x-y}{r}
\,ds $$

In my notes, this is followed by the substitution $w=\frac{x-y}{r}$, apparently giving us:
$$
=r^{n-1}\int_{|w|=1} \nabla u(y+rw)\cdot w dw=\cdots
$$

Can anyone please tell me how did we get that expression? How did our surface integral changed to a standard integral? What exactly is the Jacobian here?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that it didn't change to a standard integral. It's still a surface integral, only that it's over the unit sphere.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thank you for the insight. Can you please tell me how did the surface element $ds$ changed to $dw$, as $w \in \mathbb{R^n}$? How come the jacobian is $r^{n-1}$?

Comment: I think there is some abuse of notation. Note that in your first line of integrals you integrate over $x$ in the sense of $ds = ds(x)$, whereas after the substitution $dw$ should probably be interpreted as $ds(w)$. Which is still a surface integral as pointed out by Michał Miśkiewicz.

Comment: @SC2020 How do we justify the factor $r^{n-1}$ then?

Comment: This is still the Jacobian. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673526/how-to-change-variables-in-a-surface-integral-without-parametrizing).