# Easy question on wave equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let us be in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the wave equation $u_{tt} - \Delta_x u =0$ satisfying the initial conditions $u(0,x)=f(x)$, $u_t(0,x)=g(x)$. We define the spherical average of $u$, $U(t,r,x) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^2} \int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(t,\sigma) d \sigma$.

My question is, why is ($B(0,1)$ is the ball centered at $0$ with radius $1$)
$$U(t,r,x) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^2} \int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(t,\sigma) d \sigma = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{\partial B(0,1)} u(t,x + r \omega) d \omega?$$
Clearly we are doing change of variables, but I don't understand the part where we scale by $r^2$.

Comment: We're not scaling by $r^2$. When we plug $r=1$ into $\frac{1}{4\pi r^2}$ you just get $\frac{1}{4\pi}$.

Comment: As you said you're doing change of variables. If you calculated the Jacobian for $\omega\mapsto x+r\omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e. $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^3$) you'd get $r^3$ but you are doing change of variables *on the 2-dimensional sphere*  (i.e. $\omega\in\mathbb{S}^2$)  which is why you are missing one power.
This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673526/how-to-change-variables-in-a-surface-integral-without-parametrizing

Comment: @SvenPistre The link that you attached is very helpful. Thanks! Maybe I should learn differential geometry sometime.

Comment: Definitely do! ;)