# Area-preserving

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

A diffeomorphism $\varphi: S \to \bar{S}$ is said to be area-preserving if the area
of any region R \subset S is equal to the area of $\varphi(R)$. Prove that if $\varphi$ is
area-preserving and conformal, then ϕ is an isometry.

I have two ideas for this excersise. First, i consider a parametrization $x: U \to R \subset S$ and $\bar{x}:\varphi \circ x : X(U) \to \varphi(X(U)) $ a parametrization for $\bar{S}$. We can note that if $\varphi$ is area-preserving then $A(R)=A(\varphi(R))$. Here, i can use the definition of Area with respect to its partial derivatives and then we have that
$$A(R)=\int\int_{R}||x_{u} \times x_{v}||dudv$$
But for $\bar{S}$

$$A(\varphi(R))=\int\int ||(\varphi \circ x)_{u} \times (\varphi \circ x)_{v}||dudv$$

here i'm stuck, because i'dont know how to proceed with $A(\varphi(R))$ or how to describe the partial derivatives of the composition or use the hypotesis that $\varphi$ is conformal, i'm sure that conformal does not implies that coeficients of x and $\bar{x}$ are $\lambda$ - times of another, i.e, $\bar{E}=\lambda  E, \bar{F}= \lambda F, \bar{G}= \lambda G$, so i don't know what to do here. Another idea for this is use the definition of area with respect to first fundamental form but here the only way to develop this idea is using the wrong assumption about coefficients that i was talking about. I appreciate some idea.

**UPDATE**

i want to be sure that this attempt is good. I will proof that
$$d\varphi_{q}(x_{u})=\bar{x}_{u}$$

where $x_{u}$ and $\bar{x}_{u}$ are the partial derivatives of x and $\bar{x}$ respectively.

Now,for $(u_{0},v_{0}) \in U$ and $q=x(u_{0},v_{0}) $ and $\alpha$ a curve defined as $x(u,v_{0})=\alpha(u)$, therefore $\alpha'(u)=x_{u}(u,v_{0})$. Now, we have that

$$d\varphi_{q}(x_{u}(u_{0},v_{0}))=d\varphi_{q}(\alpha'(u_{0}))=(\varphi \circ \alpha)'(u_{0})$$

then we have that

$$d\varphi_{q}(x_{u}(u,v_{0}))=d\varphi_{q}(\alpha'(u))=(\varphi \circ \alpha)'(u)$$ for all $u$

but now, we can note that

$$(\varphi \circ \alpha)(u)=\varphi(\alpha(u))=\varphi(x(u,v_{0})=(\varphi \circ x)(u,v_{0})=\bar{x}(u,v_{0})$$

so, finally we have that
$$(\varphi \circ \alpha)'(u,v_{0})=\bar{x}_{u}(u,v_{0})$$

and we can conclude that

$$(\varphi \circ \alpha)'=d\varphi_{q}(x_{u})=\bar{x}_{u}$$

this is enought or this proof is wrong?

Comment: Roughly speaking, due to conformality, the two Riemannian metrics are related by a multiple by a positive function. The volume elements are related by this function raised to some power (related to the manifold’s dimension). Now area-preserving implies that the function has to be $1$ identically (one needs to invoke a form of the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations), so you have an isometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s say $(M,g)$ and $(\overline{M},\overline{g})$ are two Riemannian manifolds of the same dimension $n$, and $\phi:M\to \overline{M}$ is a diffeomorphism which is conformal and $n$-volume preserving (the volume being the Riemannian volume). We’ll show that $\phi$ is in fact an isometry.

First, by assumption of $\phi$ being conformal, it follows that there is a smooth positive function $f:M\to (0,\infty)$ such that $\phi^*(\overline{g})=f\cdot g$. Now, for any (nice enough $n$-dimensional) region $U\subset M$, we have the volume of $U$ equals the volume of $\phi[U]$. Let us evaluate the volume of $\phi[U]$:
\begin{align}
\text{vol}(\phi[U])&:=\int_{\phi[U]}1\,dV_{\overline{M},\overline{g}}\\
&=\int_U(1\circ \phi)\cdot dV_{M,\phi^*(\overline{g})}\tag{change of variables}\\
&=\int_U1\,dV_{M,fg}\\
&=\int_U1\cdot f^{n/2}\,dV_{M,g},
\end{align}
where I have used the [change of variables theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4059532/568204) on a Riemannian manifold, and in the final step, I used the fact that $dV_{M,fg}=f^{n/2}\,dV_{M,g}$ (this is clear from the local coordinate formula $dV_{M,g}=\sqrt{|\det g_{ij}|}\,|dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^n|$, so if you replace $g$ by $fg$, the determinant gets multiplied by $f^n$, so taking square root gives $f^{n/2}$).

So far, we have calculated the volume of $\phi[U]$ as an integral over $U$. By hypothesis, this integral is equal to the volume of $U$, i.e
\begin{align}
\int_Uf^{n/2}\,dV_{M,g}&=\int_{U}1\,dV_{M,g},
\end{align}
and this equality is supposed to hold for all nice enough regions $U$ (e.g all Borel sets $U$). If two integrals are equal for “all nice regions”, then the two integrands must be identical; this is essentially the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations (in $n$-dimensions). Thus, $f^{n/2}=1$ identically on $M$, and hence $f=1$. Thus proves $\phi$ is an isometry.

---

**Edit: Specialized version**

Parametrize the surface $S\subset\Bbb{R}^3$ as you have, $x:U\subset\Bbb{R}^2\to x[U]\subset S$. Your “first fundamental form” gives you a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix of inner products
\begin{align}
[g_{ij}]&=\begin{pmatrix}
\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\rangle &
\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial v},\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\rangle\\
\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\rangle&
\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial v},\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\rangle
\end{pmatrix}
\equiv 
\begin{pmatrix}
E&F\\
F&G
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
where $E,F,G:U\to\Bbb{R}$ are smooth functions (such that the determinant $EG-F^2$ is nowhere vanishing).
Now, since $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, you get a parametrization $\overline{x}=\phi\circ x$ of $\overline{S}$. With respect to this parametrization, as in your update, the chain rule tells you that for each $p\in U$, $\frac{\partial \overline{x}}{\partial u}(p)=d\phi_{x(p)}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(p)\right)$, and likewise with $v$. In words, the tangent vector $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(p)\in T_{x(p)}S$ is mapped via $d\phi_{x(p)}:T_{x(p)}S\to T_{\phi(x(p))}\overline{S}=T_{\overline{x}(p)}\overline{S}$ to the tangent vector $\frac{\partial \overline{x}}{\partial u}(p)\in T_{\overline{x}(p)}\overline{S}$. So, we have
\begin{align}
\left\langle \frac{\partial \overline{x}}{\partial u^i}(p),\frac{\partial \overline{x}}{\partial u^j}(p)\right\rangle_{\overline{x}(p)}
&=
\left\langle d\phi_{x(p)}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u^i}(p)\right), d\phi_{x(p)}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u^i}(p)\right)\right\rangle_{\phi(x(p))}\\
&= \lambda^2(p)
\left\langle \frac{\partial x}{\partial u^i}(p),\frac{\partial x}{\partial u^j}(p)\right\rangle_{x(p)}.
\end{align}
The first line is by the computation we just made, and the second line is the definition of conformality.
Here, for convenience, I have set $(u^1,u^2)=(u,v)$. This is saying precisely that
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\overline{E}&\overline{F}\\
\overline{F}&\overline{G}
\end{pmatrix}
&=\lambda^2
\begin{pmatrix}
E&F\\
F&G
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Finally, the norm of the cross product is $\|x_u\times x_v\|=\sqrt{EG-F^2}$. Put all of this together, and try to mimic what I said above.

(btw what I call $\lambda^2$ here (since this is how doCarmo writes it) is what I called $f$ in my original answer).

Comment: Hello, my problem is that I haven't studied anything about manifolds, so I don't understand what you did. Could you give me a hint or an outline of how the proof would be in the context of 3- dimensional real space? $R^{3)$

Comment: @LMOTRU whenever I say manifold, just imagine you have a 2-dimensional surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$. When I say Riemannian metric, think first fundamental form. Also, the determinant I mention is “$EG-F^2$”, which is nothing but the magnitude of the cross product.

Comment: And volume Will be the área that Is the Double integral by Definition? My book Is do carmo

Comment: @LMOTRU yes. $n$-dimensional volume, as I have called it here, is simply the area, which is defined by a double integral when $n=2$ (and based on your post you seem to know this idea :)

Comment: Also, although I did the computations “abstractly” you can just as easily do each step within a parametrization and do it there with formula’s you’re familiar with.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the calculations specifically. I took the parameterization as I did in my attempt, and I'm still stuck trying to find the partial derivatives of 

u and 

v. I don't understand how to use the coefficients of the first fundamental form here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146510/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-lmotru).

Comment: @LMOTRU you don’t need to evaluate any partial derivatives. You have $x_u,x_v$ and likewise with bars. From here you get your $E,F,G$ and likewise with bars. These guys are related by a positive multiple (im sure do carmo mentions something about conformality and the relationship in terms of local coordinates).

Comment: yeah, proposition 2 page 230 sec 4.2 say some like this but i am not sure that Conformal implies that these coefficientes are related by a positive multiple

Comment: that is true (especially since you’re taking the two parametrizations to be the ones related to each other by composing with $\phi$), and you should verify it. If you had taken an arbitrary parametrization for $S$ and a completely unrelated one for $\overline{S}$, then it would not be the case, but you’re taking $x$ and $\phi\circ x$, which is why things work out.

Comment: Exactly, and this parametrization $\varphi \circ x$ is the selected for me in my attempt. but how can i work with this? how can i get that for example $\bar{E}=\lambda E$  for $\bar{E} $ and $E$ coefficients of first fundamental form of  $\varphi \circ x$ and  x respectively? here we need partial derivatives but i dont know how to work with this here, and to take advantage of the fact that $\varphi$ is conformal. i'm sure that this can be used in some moment finding the coeffientes we use this fact but i don't know how can i use this.

Comment: @LMOTRU I just updated

Comment: Great! now, i want to know something, why $\frac{\partial  \bar{x}}{\partial u}(p)=\partial \varphi_{(x(p))}(\frac{\partial  x}{\partial  u}(p))$ this is the key question and the principal problem for me. the other things for me are so clearly.

Comment: @LMOTRU that’s the chain rule/ definition of the differential as a map between tangent spaces, and you pretty much wrote it in more detail using curves in your update.

Comment: does that mean that my proof about that expression in my update is correct?

Comment: @LMOTRU yes it looks correct (a little long for my taste, but that’s neither here nor there:)

Comment: A shorter proof is welcome :D I think it would help me a lot to understand these notations

Comment: @LMOTRU I would have written essentially the same thing you did, but in 2 lines. Or I would just give a “proof by knowledge” and say the equality is true (this is a very advanced proof technique:) Jokes aside, what you did is fine.

Comment: thanks a lot!! you are the best!