# If $\eta_ε$ is a mollifier, can we show $\int_{\partial B}f\ast\eta_ε\xrightarrow{ε\to0}\int_{\partial B}f$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, surface-integrals

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ with $\operatorname{supp}\eta\subseteq B_1(0)$, $\eta\ge0$, $\int\eta(x)\:{\rm d}x=1$ and $$\eta_\varepsilon(x):=\frac1{\varepsilon^d}\eta\left(\frac x\varepsilon\right)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d.$$

Now let $x\in\mathbb R^d$, $r>0$, $f:B_r(x)\to\mathbb R$ be Lebesgue integrable, $$\tilde f(y):=\begin{cases}f(y)&\text{, if }y\in B_r(x)\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}$$ for $y\in\mathbb R^d$ and $f_\varepsilon:=f\ast\eta_\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon>0$. Note that $$\left\|f_\varepsilon-f\right\|_{L^1(B_r(x)}\le\left\|f_\varepsilon-\tilde f\right\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^d)}\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\to0+}\tag10.$$

In particular, there is a sequence $(\varepsilon_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ with $\varepsilon_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ and $$f_{\varepsilon_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\tilde f\;\;\;\text{almost everywhere}\tag2.$$

> **Question**: Can we use the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that, for all $t\in(0,r)$, $$\int f_{\varepsilon_n}\:{\rm d}\sigma_{\partial B_t(x)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int f\:{\rm d}\sigma_{\partial B_t(x)}\tag3,$$ where $\sigma_{\partial B_t(x)}$ denotes the surface measure on $\mathcal B(\partial B_t(x))$?

Most probably we need to assume that $f$ is bounded to apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: What is $f_\varepsilon$? Is it the regularization of $f$ or of $\tilde{f}$?

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, sorry. I've added the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous, this convergence is true and follows from the uniform convergence of the mollified versions. Without continuity, this fails in general: You can change the values of $f$ on the null set $\partial B_t(x)$ without changing the values of the mollified functions $f_\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't understand your argumentation. Let's assume $f$ is bounded. Then $(3)$ clearly holds by the dominated convergence theorem, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it does not. For the dominated convergence theorem you need $\sigma$-a.e. convergence of the integrands, but you only have Lebesgue a.e. convergence.

Comment: Oops! You're right. Is there a useful relation between null sets of the Lebesgue-measure on $\mathcal B(\overline B_r(x))$ and $\sigma_{\partial B_r(x)}$-null sets?

Comment: No. Every subset of the interior has surface measure zero, but may have positive Lebesgue measure. Conversely, every subset of the boundary has Lebesgue measure zero, but may have positive surface measure.